# Use IFS() to switch between query statements

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to have a gird area filled out by a query.  But I want this query to change based on the selection of a drop down.  I have three different queries and I want them to swap based on drop down.

I am trying to use a IFS to switch between queries like below:

```
=iferror(
    IFS(B9="Value",
               query(LOG!A4:U,"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K WHERE A Is Not Null " 
               & IF(ISBLANK(B4),"", " AND K='"& LEFT(B4,7) &"'") & " " 
               & IF(D6<>"ALL", " AND N ='"& D6 &"'", "") & " " 
               & IF(E6<>"ALL", " AND Q ='"& E6 &"'", "") & " " 
               & IF(F6<>"ALL", " AND P ='"& F6 &"'", "") & " " 
               & IF(G6<>"ALL", " AND O ='"& G6 &"'", "") & " " 
               & IF(H6<>"ALL", " AND R ='"& H6 &"'", "") & " " 
               & IF(I6<>"ALL", " AND S ="& I6, "") & " " 
               & IF(ISBLANK(J6), "", " AND T ='"& LEFT(J6,7) &"'") & " " 
               & IF(ISBLANK(H9), "", " AND C >= date '" & text(H9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'" ) & " " 
               & IF(ISBLANK(I9), "", " AND D <= date '" & text(I9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'" ) & " "
               ,-1),
            B9 = "value 2",
        "other query
,"NO RESULTS")
```

then the value of the cell is not the value of the query, rather, this formula just returns the value of B9.

Is there a way to have different queries executed based on a cell's drop-down selection?

thanks in advance

EDIT 1:

```
=IFS(B9="WITHOUT COURSE"
   ,FILTER(PERSONNEL!A6:J
           ,(ISERROR(Match(PERSONNEL!A6:A,UNIQUE(filter(LOG!K4:K, VALUE(LOG!J4:J) = VALUE(RIGHT(B6,12)))),0)))
           , (PERSONNEL!F6:F = E6) + (E6 = "ALL") 
           , (D6 = "ALL") + (PERSONNEL!D6:D = D6)  
           , (F6 = "ALL") + (PERSONNEL!G6:G = F6)
           , (G6 = "ALL") + (PERSONNEL!E6:E = G6)
           , (H6 = "ALL") + (PERSONNEL!I6:I = H6)
           , (I6 = "ALL") + (PERSONNEL!H6:H = I6)
   )
   ,B9="WITH COURSE"
   ,query(LOG!A4:U,"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K WHERE A Is Not Null " 
        & IF(ISBLANK(B4),"", " AND K='"& LEFT(B4,7) &"'") & " " 
        & IF(D6<>"ALL", " AND N ='"& D6 &"'", "") & " " 
        & IF(E6<>"ALL", " AND Q ='"& E6 &"'", "") & " " 
        & IF(F6<>"ALL", " AND P ='"& F6 &"'", "") & " " 
        & IF(G6<>"ALL", " AND O ='"& G6 &"'", "") & " " 
        & IF(H6<>"ALL", " AND R ='"& H6 &"'", "") & " " 
        & IF(I6<>"ALL", " AND S ="& I6, "") & " " 
        & IF(ISBLANK(J6), "", " AND T ='"& LEFT(J6,7) &"'") & " " 
        & IF(ISBLANK(H9), "", " AND C >= date '" & text(H9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'" ) & " " 
        & IF(ISBLANK(I9), "", " AND D <= date '" & text(I9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "'" ) & " "
        & IF(ISBLANK(B6), "", " AND J ='"& RIGHT(B6,12) &"'") & " " 
        & IF(ISBLANK(B7), "", " AND L ='"& RIGHT(B7,12) &"'") & " "
        & IF(ISBLANK(B8), "", " AND M ='"& B8 &"'") & " " 
        & IF(B9 = "EXPIRES IN", " AND (DATEDIFF(now(), C) / 30) >= U AND U > 0 AND (DATEDIFF(now(), C) / 30) <= " &E9 & " " ,"")
    ,-1)
 )
```

Comment: have you missed semicolon: `"other query"`?

Comment: i don't see a ; in the opffical docs https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en and if I add one in it gets automatically removed

Comment: sorry, I meant double quote after a word `query"`

Comment: @MaxMakhrov thanks Max, that was just an error pasting into the site here, the actual code does have it

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `iferror` you will see the error message:

> Error
>
> IFS expects all arguments after position 0 to be in pairs.

I guess you wanted to set defaults if the formula gives an error to value "NO RESULTS". The formula would work without it you correct parentheses:

```
=iferror(
    IFS(B9="Value",
             "some value",
         B9 = "value 2",
            "other query")
,"NO RESULTS")
```

Comment: thanks mark, for some reason when I use the IFS only one row is returned when the query should return 100+ rows. see my edit for the new version